# Can the Close / Minimize / Maximize buttons be pulled out of the Global App Menu when a window is maximized?

Tags: 11.04, unity, panel

I've disabled the Unity Global AppMenu as it personally drives me batty - I've also moved my minimize / maximize buttons back to the right hand side of the windows where I like them.

However, when I maximize a window, the minimize / maximize / close buttons get pushed into the top panel on the left, next to where the Global AppMenu would be if I hadn't disabled it.

I would prefer if maximizing a window functioned exactly the same as if I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num 5</kbd>

Is this possible?

Comment: You should mark this is as solved btw.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is hard coded into unity, but if we push really hard, we might be able to get them to change it for 11.10 (file a bug, or mark an existing bug for it as affecting you).

Comment: Well, if it's affecting anyone else, please feel free to share your thoughts here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/775346

Comment: @SteveComrie: I marked it as affecting me - now time to make some noise about it :).

Comment: Ugh. I keep thinking I'll get used to Unity and haven't yet.