# Is there a way to get the Unity title bar behavior and NOTHING ELSE?

Tags: unity, panel, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove maximized window controls/title from top panel in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25789/is-there-a-way-to-remove-maximized-window-controls-title-from-top-panel-in-unity)

I know how to get app menus in the panel. I like the fact that in Unity, the top panel effectively becomes the title bar for maximized windows. Apart from that, Unity is driving me up the pole. Is there a way to get the Unity window maximization behavior with Ubuntu "Classic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick scout about it appears that unity isn't modular at present, so you can't have the globalmenu without unity.

**But** you can effectively remove the unity dock from your desktop.

Install CCSM `apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Under the Ubuntu Unity Plugin section make the following changes:

- Reveal Mode: Change this so that none of the edges are selected
- Set Hide Launcher to 'Auto-hide'
- Clear the short-cut keys

That will make the unity dock disappear immediately after launching.

You can then get your gnome-panels back by adding 'gnome-panel' to your start-up applications using the control centre.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install just the globalmenu from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/). It works in almost the same way as unity's - with the only difference being that it doesn't hide the menus when the mouse is far from the bar.

This way you can use the features classic has (more panels if you want to, applets on the panels etc) and have more space as well.

edit : i also found [this](http://www.bbgamer.co.uk/archives/109) which seems even easier than my first idea - simple 3-4 clicks at maximum