# How do you disable launcher without disabling global menus in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, launcher, globalmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get the Unity title bar behavior and NOTHING ELSE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45531/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-unity-title-bar-behavior-and-nothing-else)

How do you disable the launcher WITHOUT DISABLING the global menus too in 11.04? I want to use Docky instead of Launcher.

Thanks.

Comment: short answer: you can't remove and/or move the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

long answer: you can get the global menu behavior another way,

in classical mode you can add the 'indicator applet app menu' to any panel (i recommend the top for emulating the unity global menu)